# How to measure property awarded as treasure

Tags: dnd-5e, campaign-development, treasure

I want to award property and land as a reward for a set of adventures. I'm creating a campaign in 5th Edition, and I want to follow the treasure per level guidelines. I know I can measure the building's value, but what about the land it is on? Is there any source material that would include land itself?

Comment: Are you looking for a wealth by level model like 3.5 D&D?  If so, 5e doesn't have that explicitly spelled out.  If that isn't what you are looking for, I am perhaps misreading your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn’t worry much about the value of any property that you give your players. In 5e, wealth by level isn’t assumed in the balance of the game and the lack of a magic item economy makes it very hard to unbalance the game by giving you players too much money.

In a medieval setting, the value of property is going to come from a mix of strategic concerns and income it produces. Strategic value really just gives your players more opportunities for roleplaying and it is as likely to cost money (we need to hire guards to protect this trade road now) than to generate it. Income, as Garret Gang mentioned in his comment, is basically completely under the DM’s control. Are you worried that your players’ farm is giving them too much money? Bandit attack during the harvest! Now you’ve limited their income *and* given them a new quest, one that they’re likely to be highly invested in.

Basically, my opinion is that you can’t go wrong with giving your players property. It makes them more invested in the game world, generates limitless quest and roleplaying opportunities, and is just likely to be a treasure sink (but one that they enjoy putting money into) as a source of income.

I realize that doesn’t strictly answer your question. If you’re concerned about limited treasure, would value property on the net monthly income it generates.

Comment: Since we have a fairly detailed revision history on each post, you don't need to signal your edits on the site. Just write them as if the post had always contained your edits. I've tried to do that for you here, but if you feel I've done your answer harm, feel free to fix it up with another edit!

Comment: I think this answers my question. Since there may not be a reference in source material that values the land, I can instead go off of the income it provides, which then can follow into the section in the DMG or PHB that talks about earning money from a business. I'm right there with you, the land can lead to much more, like investment in the campaign, or additional adventures, which is why I want to give it. Thanks for the perspective.